# What is the prakAra-prakAri (attribute-substance) relationship between Brahman and Jiva in Vishishtadvaita?

Tags: brahman, vishishtadvaita, jiva

As far as I know, Vishishtadvaita has seven types of Brahman-Jiva relationships:

- sharIra/sharIrI (body/indweller)
- **prakAra/prakArI (attribute/substance)**
- shesha/sheshi (owned/owner)
- niyamya/niyanta (controlled/controller)
- amsha/amshI (part/whole)
- adhAradeya/sambandha (supporter/supported)
- rashksya/rakshaka (redeemed/redeemer)

Now, I'm interested in the one given in bold i.e. prakAra-prakAri (attribute-substance) relationship between Brahman and Jiva. Can anybody explain me this relation in detail with proper scriptural references and examples?

Comment: Seen Vedanta / Philosophical question after long time!

Comment: Why the downvotes? 

Comment: I have upvoted. Don't know why downvote.

Comment: Adding a comment as I have no scriptural references. Just as blueness is an inseparable attribute of a blue lotus, or yellowness of gold, so is the Soul an inseparable attribute/mode (Prakara) of God substance (Prakari).